# Is it possible to enable source.organizeImports without removal of unused imports?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is what I have in my user `settings.json`.

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.organizeImports": true
},
```

Love the sorting, but don’t like that Visual Studio Code is removing unused imports vs greying them out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36085

Answer (score 43):

Finally it's possible in 2021.

Replace `source.organizeImports` by `source.sortImports`.

```js
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.sortImports": true
},
```